# Android Studio drawing with atlas

Tags: java, android, 2d, platform

I'm trying to draw a selection of my spritesheet on my screen but im getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.flappybird.game.FlappyBird.create(FlappyBird.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:146)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:123)
```

Here is the code i made.

```
package com.flappybird.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;

public class FlappyBird extends ApplicationAdapter {
private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
private Sprite sprite;
public OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet.pack"));
    sprite = textureAtlas.createSprite("Background1");
    sprite.setPosition(sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
    camera.position.set(10,20,0);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
}
```

can someone help my with this ? i would really appreciated :)

Comment: What's your 21th line code?

Comment: @FireSun 'sprite.setPosition(sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());'

Comment: ,Looks like sprite is null,you can check this at first.

Comment: @FireSun this is thee image i packed  'spritesheet.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
spritesheet
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 512, 512
  orig: 512, 512
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1'